# Value of type bool is not callable PHP

Tags: php, fatal-error

I'm having a bit of trouble with this simple rock paper scissors game I'm making.

So I want to make a the computer chose a random of the 3.
This is how to code looks.

```
128 $array = array("Rock","Paper","Scissors");
129 $shuf = shuffle($array);
130 $computer = $shuf(0);
```

When I fire the website up using xampp I get an error messeage looking like this.

> Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Value of type bool is not callable in on line 130

Any solution to this?
Thanks!

Comment: `shuffle` is an inplace function. It alters the array, it doesn't return a new shuffled array. `$shuf`  is a bool, since that is what `shuffle` returns.

Comment: `$computer = $array[0];` shuffle returns true or false not the shuffled array, and arrays are addressed with `[]` and not `()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [docs](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.shuffle.php) says that `shuffle` modifies the input array and returns `true` on success and `false` on failure. So, you need to check its result and if so, perform your logical operations on the input array, that was passed by reference and modified while the `function` was being executed:

```
$shuf = array("Rock","Paper","Scissors");
if (shuffle($shuf)) { //success
    $computer = $shuf[0]; //$shuf was modified during the shuffling
} else {
    //the shuffling failed, you can handle failure here
}
```